# HTML Conditional Comment exhibits strange behavior in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, conditional-comments

Please look at this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("IE7")</script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("IE8")</script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript">alert("IE9")</script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body data-pagename="home">

</body>
</html>
```

I can't understand why if I view it in IE8 and IE7 all works fine, while if I view the page in IE9,  the alert is as if I were in IE7.
 If I change the firsts lines before the head tag with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
```

all works fine.

As if something between the doctype and the head changes the rendering beahviour.
The question are: 
is it a my fault, maybe beacause I'm using something in an illegal way or is it an IE9 fault?

Comment: What if you remove the first two conditional alerts completely but leave all of the `<html>` tags there?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on IE9.  Are you sure you didn't accidentally change the browser mode? Check F12.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx I didn't change the browser mode. I only load the page after close/open the browser.

Comment: @BoltClock no alerts. If I move IE8 alert before the IE7 alert I've IE7.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why if I view it in IE8 and IE7 all works fine, while if I view the page in IE9, the alert is as if I were in IE7.

It's complicated:

- Is "Display All Sites in Compatibility View" set?

  - Is "User Compatibility View List" enabled?

    - Is a match found?
  - Is "MS Compatibility View List" enabled?

    - Is a match found?
  - Is "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View" set?

    - Is the webpage in the "Intranet Zone"?

**References**

- [Determining IE9 Document Mode(SVG)](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg)
- [Determining IE9 Document Mode(PNG)](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_3.png)
- [IE(9) Compatibility Features for Site Developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx)